# matmul with non-conforming matrices

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I expected the intrinsic matmul to fail when multiplying non-conforming matrices. In this simple example (see a simple code below), I am multiplying a 4x3 matrix by 4x4 matrix using matmul. Interestingly the intel compiler does not issue any warning or fatal error message at either the run-time or compile time. I tried '-check all' flag and it did not catch this error, either. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

P.S. gfortran does complain about this operation

```
    program main

       implicit none

       interface

          subroutine shouldFail(arrayInput, scalarOutput)

             implicit none

             real (8), intent(in) :: arrayInput(:,:)
             real (8), intent(out) :: scalarOutput

          end
       end interface

       real (8) :: scalarOutput, arrayInput(4, 3)


       arrayInput(:,:) = 1.0
       call shouldFail(arrayInput, scalarOutput)

       write(*,*) scalarOutput

    end program main




    !#############################################

    subroutine shouldFail(arrayInput, scalarOutput)

       implicit none
       real (8), intent(in) :: arrayInput(:,:)
       real (8), intent(out) :: scalarOutput
       real (8) :: jacobian(3, 4), derivative(4, 4)

       derivative(:,:) = 1.0

       jacobian = matmul(arrayInput, derivative)

       scalarOutput = jacobian(1, 2)

    end subroutine shouldFail
```

Comment: My eyes, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this and note that `real(8)` is not portable.

Comment: What is the question? What kind of thoughts you want to see? Just to confirm whether the code is illegal or explain why the compiler accepts it? Likely only Intel developers can tell you why their compiler does something. They have a good support forum.

Comment: @VladimirF Portability is not of concern here specifically, as you pointed out later. I am mainly interested in knowing why the Intel compiler cannot catch this misuse of matmul. I have posted this concern to the Intel forum, too

Comment: How do you expect this to fail at compile time and with what sort of error? Just because your invocation of shouldFail is wrong it doesn't mean that the subroutine itself is wrong - and as written the compiler isn't guaranteed to be able to "see" the source of shouldFail at the calling point, so diagnosing the mismatch would be impossible. Oh, and please fix real( 8 ), let's stop propagating this poor practice.

Comment: @IanBush I expect the compiler to throw an error at either the compile time or run-time due to the mismatch of the matrix sizes. However the intel compiler is completely silent and let this error slip by it

Comment: @Ahmad But as written it can be all but impossible for the compiler to detect this error. Imagine the routine is in a separate file and compiled first. How can an error then be thrown as it does not know what arguments it will receive? Runtime is different, and I agree, any decent implementation should throw an error. But compile time is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

On Intel REAL(8) is consistent, so moving onto the question...

The answer is here: software.intel.com/en-us/node/693211

If array input has shape (n, m) and derivative has shape (m, k), the result is a rank-two array (Jacobite) with shape (n, k)...

Whether one needs/want to add in USE ISO_C_BINDING and then using REAL(KIND=C_FLOAT) can be worthwhile for some conceptual future where it need to be portable... (Usually after the MATMUL is convincing one that it works).

It could look like this:

```
subroutine shouldFail(arrayInput, scalarOutput)
USE ISO_C_BINDING
implicit none
real(KIND=C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(:,:), intent(in   ) :: arrayInput
real(KIND=C_DOUBLE)                , intent(  out) :: scalarOutput
real(KIND=C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(3,4)                :: Jacobian
real(KIND=C_DOUBLE), DIMENSION(4,4)                :: derivative

(Here: You may want to consider checking the rank/shape before the MATMUL call if you are concerned.)
```

Comment: The real(8) is just a comment, no need to tackle it in the answer. And yes it is consistent in Intel, I never said it isn't, but portability means moving between different compilers and it *is* useful. But no need to tackle it in an answer at all.

Comment: I think the answer would benefit from more explanation about the issue from that forum (and making the link clickable). I still don't understand what is going on from your short excerpt. It is not a link-only answer, but the explanation is still very short.

Comment: There is no way to tender way to say that the compiler that is not broken... MATMUL can be done on matrices of different size. A common one is (H , TRANSPOSE(H))

Comment: I am not saying it is, I am asking for more explanation. In the answer, not in a comment.

Comment: No. matmul(H , TRANSPOSE(H)) is valid whatever the shape of H. If H is a mxn matrix then transpose(H) is a nxm matrix, and the product of a mxn and a nxm matrix is valid, and is a square mxm matrix